# Language difference in full text search for numeric strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

If I create this table on SQL Server 10.50.2550 (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  number VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG test_catalog;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON test
  (
    number Language 0
  )
  KEY INDEX test_pk
  ON test_catalog;
  ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON test START UPDATE POPULATION;

INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES ('1111111111');
INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES ('1111111112');
```

And when the index is populated perform the query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE CONTAINS(*, '1111111111');
```

I get this:

```
id                   number
-------------------- ----------
1                    1111111111
2                    1111111112

(2 row(s) affected)
```

If I change the language to English (1033), if I only use 9-digit numbers or if I use SQL Server 11.0.3128 (SQL Server 2012) I only get the expected one row.

Do I do anything wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472890/language-difference-in-full-text-search-for-numeric-strings , but I hope it is alright to ask the question both here and on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Better to migrate than to repost twice. Hopefully the mods will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this is the bug: [SQL Server 2008 full-text query may return false positives using number with more than 9 digits as search predicate condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2280126).

Unfortunately the resolution does not work for Danish language.